# ORACLE PIVOT QUERY 10G

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, pivot

The Requirement is to reporoduce the results in pivot table format.

we have 22 tables each month each table have about 1.5 million rows. The desired output is we 22 table holding information each product/category  and need to product in column format

in 11g we used pivot function to reproduct and 10g we have written the following query . This query keep on running for 1 day and not returing any results , since the max aggregate function taking huge time to compute.   Is there any way to rewrite the following query .

```
SELECT year,month,account_id,media_id,status,
        max(CP1) AS                 CP,
        max(CA1) AS                 CA,
        max(CU1) AS                    CU,
        max(GENDER1) AS                  GENDER,
        max(AGE1)  AS                AGE,
        max(AREA1) AS               AREA,
        max(SB1) AS               SB,
        max(SSP1) AS             SSP,
        max(SRP) AS            scheme_redem_prpt,
        max(BAL1) AS         BAL,
        max(PTS_RE1) AS       PTS_RE,
        max(PTS_EA1) AS      PTS_EA,
        max(dept_01_txn1) AS                dept_01_txn,
        max(dept_02_txn1) AS                dept_02_txn,
        max(dept_03_txn1) AS                dept_03_txn,
        max(dept_04_txn1) AS                dept_04_txn,
        max(dept_05_txn1) AS                dept_05_txn,
        max(dept_01_amt1) AS              dept_01_amt,
        max(dept_02_amt1) AS              dept_02_amt,
        max(dept_03_amt1) AS              dept_03_amt,
        max(dept_04_amt1) AS              dept_04_amt,
        max(dept_05_amt1) AS              dept_05_amt
  FROM (SELECT year,month,account_id,media_id,status,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('CR1') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS CP1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('CR2')  , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS CA1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('CR3')   , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS CU1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('GENDER') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS GENDER1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('AGE') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS AGE1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('AREA') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS AREA1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('SB1') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS SB1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('SB2') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS SSP1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('SB3') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS SRP,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('SR1') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS BAL1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('SR2') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS PTS_RE1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('SR3') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS PTS_EA1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_01_TXN') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_01_txn1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_02_TXN') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_02_txn1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_03_TXN') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_03_txn1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_04_TXN') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_04_txn1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_05_TXN'), prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_05_txn1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_01_AMT') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_01_amt1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_02_AMT') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_02_amt1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_03_AMT') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_03_amt1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_04_AMT') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_04_amt1,
                nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('DEPT_05_AMT') , prdatt_value, null),'00') AS dept_05_amt1
         FROM (
            select year, month, account_id,  media_id,prdatt_id, prdatt_iid, prdatt_value , status 
              from ac_prd_tab_01
            union all
            select year, month, account_id,  media_id,prdatt_id, prdatt_iid, prdatt_value , status 
              from ac_prd_tab_02
            union all
            select year, month, account_id,  media_id,prdatt_id, prdatt_iid, prdatt_value , status 
              from ac_prd_tab_03
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_04 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
              from ac_prd_tab_05 a,
                   dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
              from ac_prd_tab_06 a,
                   dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
              from ac_prd_tab_07 a,
                   dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id
            union all 
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_08 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id 
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_09 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_10 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_11 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id 
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_12 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id 
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_13 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id 
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_14 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_15 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_16 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id 
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_17 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id 
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
              from ac_prd_tab_18 a,
                   dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_19 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_20 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_21 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            union all
            select a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
            from ac_prd_tab_22 a,
                 dtl_monthly b 
            where a.year= b.year and a.month=b.month and a.account_id=b.account_id  
            )
       )
  GROUP BY year,month,account_id, media_id,status
/
```

Comment: Reading your query wasn't fun.

Comment: @mucio I would not write that query.

Answer (score 1):

Beside the max you are also using a lot of functions.

First of all instead of

```
   SELECT a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
     FROM ac_prd_tab_21 a,
          dtl_monthly b 
    WHERE a.year= b.year AND a.month=b.month AND a.account_id=b.account_id  
UNION ALL
   SELECT a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
     FROM ac_prd_tab_22 a,
             dtl_monthly b 
    WHERE a.year= b.year AND a.month=b.month AND a.account_id=b.account_id
        ...
```

I will try

```
   SELECT a.year, a.month, a.account_id, b.media_id , a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
     FROM (

   SELECT a.year, a.month, a.account_id, a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
     FROM ac_prd_tab_21 a
UNION ALL
   SELECT a.year, a.month, a.account_id, a.prdatt_id, a.prdatt_iid, a.prdatt_value , a.status 
     FROM ac_prd_tab_22 a
          )
INNER JOIN dtl_monthly b 
        ON a.year= b.year AND a.month=b.month AND a.account_id=b.account_id
```

Second thing, I will try to split the query in multiple steps which populate real tables, maybe in a procedure.

Third thing, if you use a procedure instead to calculate every time the values of `util_pkg.fnc_get_Value()` put them in some variables like `vCR1 := util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('CR1')`, then  this:

```
nvl(decode(prdatt_id,util_pkg.fnc_get_Value('CR1') , prdatt_value, null),'00')
```

will become this:

```
nvl(decode(prdatt_id, vCR1, prdatt_value, null),'00')
```

Additional small thing

```
(decode(prdatt_id, vCR1, nvl(prdatt_value, '00'), '00')
```

This should be enough to start.

Comment: +1 for even taking a run at it.

Comment: @ mucio ..thanks for your suggestions ... fyi  i tried the query with out max and its running fine .... only thing i added to max to pivot those rows to cols.   mean while i try to run the query tiwht ur suggestions